# Replacing a paramater in SQL for a foreign key

Tags: c#, sql

```
SELECT 
    StaffID, 
    SUM(Treatment.TreatmentPrice) AS TotalStaffRevenue, 
    SUM(Treatment.TreatmentPrice) * ? AS Commission
FROM 
    Treatment
INNER JOIN 
    Appointment ON Appointment.TreatmentID = Treatment.TreatmentID
WHERE
    AppointmentDate >= '2018/05/11' 
    AND AppointmentDate <= '2018/05/12'
GROUP BY 
    staffid WITH ROLLUP

CREATE TABLE Staff (
StaffID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
Forename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Surname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
MobileNumber varchar(11) NOT NULL,
EmailAddress varchar(20) NULL,
PostCode varchar(8) NULL,
HouseNumber varchar(4) NULL,
Commission decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(StaffID)
);

GO

CREATE TABLE Treatment (
TreatmentID int identity NOT NULL,
TreatmentName varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
TreatmentPrice money NOT NULL,
CategoryID int NOT NULL,
TreatmentDescription varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(TreatmentID, CategoryID)
);

GO

CREATE TABLE Appointment (
AppointmentID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
StaffID int NOT NULL,
TreatmentID int NOT NULL,
CustomerID int NOT NULL,
AppointmentDate date NOT NULL,
AppointmentTime time(0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (AppointmentID, StaffID, CustomerID, TreatmentID)
);
```

I want the ability to multiply the sum of TreatmentPrice by Staff.Commission. I have tried INNER JOINing with Staff but it still doesn't work also how would I implement this in the front end (c#) would i use a for each loop, this would then populate a datagrid.

Comment: If Commission is in the Staff table then it sounds like an `INNER JOIN` is most likely the way to go here. Can you update the post with the Create Table statements for those 3 tables?

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Where is staff join?

Comment: i dont know how to do it without getting an error for Staff.Commission

Answer (score 0):

How did you get Staff.Commission without any join to the Staff table in your query?
Try

```
SELECT 
    Staff.StaffID, 
    SUM(Treatment.TreatmentPrice) AS TotalStaffRevenue, 
    SUM(Treatment.TreatmentPrice)*Commission AS Commission
FROM 
    Treatment
INNER JOIN 
    Appointment ON Appointment.TreatmentID = Treatment.TreatmentID
    inner join Staff on Appointment.StaffID=Staff.StaffID
WHERE
    AppointmentDate >= '2018/05/11' 
    AND AppointmentDate <= '2018/05/12'
GROUP BY 
    Staff.StaffID,Commission WITH ROLLUP
```